# Can i fetch the data from SQL database table without using any Query...????? in vb or C#

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

Can i fetch the data from SQL database table without using any Query...????? in vb or C#

Comment: You can't spell SQL without Query

Comment: What are you trying to do?  It is possible to archive tables from SQL, but that is usually done from the database although it can be performed using the utility sqlcmd.exe.  I've used sqlcmd.exe from a c# process in one of my applications.

Comment: yes....!!!! but not with using the select and such types of queries

Comment: if we use datatable object then it is possible or not...????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with the "Linq" infrastructure.

A little C# sample:

```
var q =
 from c in db.Customers
 where c.City == "London"
 select c;
// Execute first time
foreach (Customer c in q)
   Console.WriteLine(c.CompanyName);
// Execute second time
foreach (Customer c in q)
  Console.WriteLine(c.CompanyName);
```

It comes from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx